# Is it possible to change the default build directory in Dart?

Tags: dart

When I run `pub build`, pub puts the compiled app into `build/web`. Is it possible to configure my `pubspec.yaml` file to change the default output directory to, say, `prod`?

**EDIT**: I'm trying to avoid having to use the `--output` switch each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pub build --output=someOtherDir`
See also `pub help build`

Comment: Yeah, I know... I'm looking for a way to change the default behavior. I've updated the question to be more clear about that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't. I suggest using Grinder or batch scripts to automate such tasks.

Comment: Bummer. Fabric to the rescue, I suppose.